Utilize the LinkedIn API with React and Flask to retrieve user profile data
I have this react project which includes using LinkedIn API to get user's profile data such as Activity, Education, Skills, Experience and Interests. I am able to connect to LinkedIn API and get the access token. I am having trouble understanding how to use the API to get the profile data
This is my first react project, a huge percentage of my code is AI-generated. I am not 100% clear on the code I've written. Below are the code files, that are involved in the function.
LinkedInCallback.js
It handles the callback from LinkedIn's OAuth authorization flow.
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const LinkedInCallback = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
        const authorizationCode = queryParams.get("code")

        if (authorizationCode) {
            axios
            .post("http://localhost:5000/profile/linkedin/auth", {code:authorizationCode})
            .then((response) => {
                const accessToken = response.data.access_token
                console.log("Access token received: ", accessToken);
                document.cookie = `accessToken=${accessToken}; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Strict; Expires=${new Date(Date.now() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)}`;
                navigate('/profile/linkedin/data');         
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error fetching access token:", error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
            });
        }
    }, [navigate]);
    return <div>Logging in with LinkedIn...</div>;
};

export default LinkedInCallback;

LinkedInProfile.js
This functional component fetches a user's LinkedIn work experience data using an access token and displays the data on the page
import React, { useEffect, useState} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const LinkedInProfile = () => {
    const [workExperience, setWorkExperience] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const accessToken = getCookie("accessToken");

        if (accessToken) {
            console.log("Access token found. Fetching work experience...");           
            axios.get("https://localhost:5000/proxy/linkedin/positions", {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                },
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log("Work experience data fetched succesfully")
                setWorkExperience(response.data);
                setLoading(false)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error("Error fetching work experience", error)
                setLoading(false)
            })   
    } else {
        console.error("No access token found. Please authenticate");
        setError("Access token not found.Please log in.")
        setLoading(false)
    } 
}, []);

    if (loading) {
        return <p>Loading work experience...</p>
    }

    if (error) {
        return <p>Error: {error}</p>;
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Test house for linkedin data</h1>
            <h2>LinkedIn Work Experience</h2>
            {workExperience ? (
                <pre>{JSON.stringify(workExperience, null, 2)}</pre>
            ): (<p>Loading work experience...</p>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
export default LinkedInProfile

LinkedInLogin.js
This functional component redirects the user to the LinkedIn authorization URL when called.
import React from "react";

const linkedinAuthUrl = `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&scope=openid%20email%20profile`;

const LinkedInLogin = () => {
    const handleLogin = () => {
        window.location.href = linkedinAuthUrl
    };
    return <button onClick={handleLogin}>Login with LinkedIn</button>
}

export default LinkedInLogin;

app.py
@app.route("/profile/linkedin/auth", methods=["POST"])
@cross_origin(origin = "http://localhost:3000", supports_credentials=True)
def linkedin_auth():
    authorization_code = request.json.get("code")

    access_token_url = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken"
    data = {
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "code": authorization_code,
        "redirect_uri": REDIRECT_URI,
        "client_id": CLIENT_ID,
        "client_secret": CLIENT_SECRET
    }

    response = requests.post(access_token_url, data)
    response_data = response.json()

    access_token = response_data.get("access_token")
    if access_token:
        print(access_token)
        return jsonify({"access_token": access_token})
    else:
        print("Linkedin error response: ", response_data)
        return jsonify({"error": "Failed to obtain access token", "details": response_data}), 400

@cross_origin(origin = "http://localhost:3000", supports_credentials=True)
@app.route("/proxy/linkedin/positions", methods=["GET"])
def get_linkedin_positions():
    access_token = request.headers.get("Authorization")
    if not access_token:
        return jsonify({"error": "Access token is required"}), 401
    
    linkedin_url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/~?projection=(positions)"
    headers= {"Authorization": access_token}

    response = requests.get(linkedin_url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        return jsonify(response.json())
    else:
        return jsonify({"error": "Failed to fetch data", "details": response.json()}), response.status_code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True, ssl_context="adhoc")


What route is not working for you? Maybe try first using Postman to see how you can use it.
